# How to change the color of the console in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

I have a dark theme (IR Black) in Sublime Text 2, but the console comes up white on black.

Is there a way to change the console colors?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4583&p=20807#p20807

\Packages\Theme - Default\Widget.sublime-settings

```
{
    // "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Default/Widgets.stTheme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Blackboard.tmTheme"
}
```

Comment: This changes the colors in the text area as well though, doesn't it?

Comment: The `Widgets.stTheme` must be a separate setting -- my (very) custom editor color scheme isn't affected.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with your theme, but the beautiful Soda theme has a dark version, and all panels (including console) are dark:

https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme

[image: Soda Dark Theme]
<sub>(source: [github.com](http://buymeasoda.github.com/soda-theme/images/screenshots/soda-dark-theme.png?v=7))</sub>

Comment: That is pretty nice, right now I'm using a customized IR Black theme (https://github.com/chambery/Sublime-Text-Settings/blob/master/Color%20Scheme%20-%20Default/IR_Black.tmTheme), I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this package out, works like a charm:

https://github.com/ehamiter/ST2-Color-Console

Answer (score 2):

Or use

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"
}
```

to match the Monokai default of Sublime in the console's settings:

/sublime/Data/Packages/Theme - Default\Widget.sublime-settings