# changing console color sublime text 3 (modifying Widget)

Tags: colors, console, sublimetext

Where can I find these folders on Mac (Sublime Text 3)?  I succesfully found them on my PC (Sublime Text 2) and modified the theme to where now console and  editor are the same background, but I cannot find the   `Packages\Theme - Default\Widget.sublime-settings` path on my Mac.  I did notice that the build window was a different color from the main editor on my PC until I updated the config's below, however on my mac and ST3 the build menu automatically is the same (console is still not though, whereas it is on the PC post-changes).

```
{
    // "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Default/Widgets.stTheme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Blackboard.tmTheme"
}
```

Thanks for the help, FYI this is the thread I referenced: [How to change the color of the console in sublime text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760188/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-console-in-sublime-text)

Comment: I appreciate the effort but my question is more specifically around the widget.sublime-settings file, I know how to access the packages folder, what I can't do is find this file to modify the console settings.

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text 3, a `Widget.sublime-settings` file is located in `Packages/Default` *and* `Packages/Theme - Default`. Install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, then access its `Open Resource` function through the Command Palette to open whichever file(s) you're interested in editing. You can simply save the file(s) when you're done.